# Django: Database column not updating from variable, taking it as hardcoded name

Tags: python, django, django-models

I have the following code for updating a database column.

```
def update_itemamadeus(check_flight_differences):

    for item_id, flight_details in check_flight_differences.items():

        for field, value in flight_details.items():

            ItemAmadeus.objects \
                .filter(
                    Q(id=item_id)
                ) \
                .update(
                    field = value
                )
    return
```

It's taking 'field' not as the variable it should be which is 'code_airport_from_id'.

[image]

```
item_id = 130
field   = code_airport_from_id
value   = BCN
```

The dreaded yellow screen error:

[image]

Can this be achieved?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to convert the parameters as dictionary and pass it through function by unpacking them, like this:

```
ItemAmadeus.objects \
            .filter(
                Q(id=item_id)
            ) \
            .update(
                **{field:value}
            )
```

This [article on geeksforgeeks](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/packing-and-unpacking-arguments-in-python/) has some examples of unpacking.